# ReferenceError: Property '__scanCodes' doesn't exist . In vision-camera-code-scanner. React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

When I try to run my project with xcode 15. I got the error

> ReferenceError: Property '__scanCodes' doesn't exist

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "flap",
  "version": "0.8.50",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "android-clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "arch -x86_64 react-native run-ios --scheme flap --simulator='iPhone 14 Pro Max'",
    "ios14pro": "arch -x86_64 react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 14 Pro'",
    "ios12pm": "arch -x86_64 react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 12 Pro Max'",
    "iosNicat": "arch -x86_64 react-native run-ios --device `Nicat's iPhone`",
    "iosX": "arch -x86_64 react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone X'",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "clear": "react-native start -- --reset-cache",
    "pod": "cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install && cd ..",
    "pod-update": "cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update && cd ..",
    "derived": "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.1",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "16.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.8",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^3.0.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "npm": "^9.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.11.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.1",
    "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.14.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-share": "^8.0.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vcards": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "2.15.4",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "^0.2.4",
    "serialize-error": "^11.0.2",
    "vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

my babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ["react-native-worklets-core/plugin"],
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanCodes']
      },
    ]
  ],
};
```

The error :

> ReferenceError: Property '__scanCodes' doesn't exist
> at scanCodes (/Users/mahabbatzakariyayev/Documents/workprojects/flap/node_modules/vision-camera-code-scanner/src/index.ts
> (300:7):1:49)
> at scanCodes (native)
> at _f (/Users/mahabbatzakariyayev/Documents/workprojects/flap/node_modules/vision-camera-code-scanner/src/hook.tsx
> (13:43):1:121)
> at _f (native)
> at _f (/Users/mahabbatzakariyayev/Documents/workprojects/flap/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/src/hooks/useFrameProcessor.ts
> (28:21):1:425)

I have also applied this to my project otherwise it didn't open the camera: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1802#issuecomment-1728167110

I deleted all pods ,node_modules and etc. But it again gives this error.

Comment: Might you consider using Expo to avoid having to muck around in the "native bits" of RN yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I made hermesenabled false in PodFile. Then clean install and everything works find now!